# How to word align in Mapper using hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Source Code below :

```
public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    /*
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
     */     
        
            String delimeter = " ";
            String[] temp;
            String token = value.toString();
            temp = token.split(delimeter);
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
               for(int j=0;j < temp.length;j++){
                   word.set(temp[i]+","+temp[j]);
                   context.write(word, one);
               }
            }
            
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

I rewrite the WordCountv1.0 version for our purpose

## focus on map function

thinking :
if input data will `a b c d`
I tear them apart to `a ,b ,c ,d`

and do the word align for result like : `aa,ab ,ac ,ad,ba,bb,bc,bd ....`

and give it a word count 1

```
context.write(word, one);
```

and throw it to reduce for count calculate

but it doesn't works, how should I change my code??

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the variable word that is

`private Text word;`

instead of

```
  private Text word = new Text();
```

And change the for loop as below:-

```
String delimeter = " ";
            String[] temp;
            String token = value.toString();
            temp = token.split(delimeter);
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
               for(int j=0;j < temp.length;j++){
                 word = new Text(temp[i]+temp[j]);
                 context.write(word, one);
               }
            }
```

Comment: temp.length will be a small count if input data is very huge

Comment: a 1 b 1 c 1 d 1 is this your output?? can you print the temp[i] and temp[j]

Comment: yes ,it's my output,it's that any example that i could store temp[i] and temp[j] into file when I run the hadoop

Comment: we are actually appending temp[i] and temp[j] so we should be getting like aa,ab,ac... right?

Comment: <word,one> --><aa,1><ab,1>....., i have to find what's going on= =in these two parameter

Comment: what is that = = parameter? after changing the code as i have given what is the final output you are getting

Comment: that's the result it should be after mapper, final output just the a1 b1 c1 d1

Comment: can you set the number of reducers to zero comment out the reducer config and check the output